# Not able to rotate only the border around the circle and not the image or content

Tags: html, css

I have created the circle around the image and I want to rotate the border only, not the image.

This is the image that I wanted to create and rotate only the blue border, not the image.

[image]

**I have created like this:**

```css
#circle2 {
  width: 210px;
  height: 210px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 6px solid #337AB7;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
}

#circle2 img {
display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle2">
  <div class="elementor-widget-container">
    <div class="elementor-image">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/WkdnS0f/BIcon-1.png" class="attachment-large size-large">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

I want to rotate the blue border around the image not the image.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try using `:before` or `:after` and rotating that.

Comment: Basic concept is to not put the image in the border, could be done with pseudo elements or actual element, just position them absolutely to get the layering/border look

Comment: @YaakovAinspan. Can you please write code for it?

Comment: @Huangism Can you please write code for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spin the container and set child to spin the other way at the same time...

```css
#circle2  {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 6px solid #337AB7;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: spin 5s linear infinite;
}

.elementor-widget-container {
  animation: spin 5s linear infinite reverse;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;

}

img {
display:block;
}
@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="circle2">
  <div class="elementor-widget-container">
    <div class="elementor-image">
      <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/200/200" class="attachment-large size-large">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you could try giving `position:absolute;` to the image, add `animation: example  5s linear infinite;` at the bottom of `#circle2` and at the bottom of your css add something like:

```
@keyframes example{
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```